# Are there any free Thai fonts that I can use for the web?

Tags: website-design, fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I work at a web agency and need a Thai web font. I've already found Tahoma, but my boss wanted me to find an alternative license free font for the web.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about resource and intelligence gathering, which has nothing to do with Graphic Design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter Google fonts by language and you get many options:
[Thai Fonts on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=thai)

Answer (score 2):

Some Google fonts are available in Thai. They are free to use and specifically designed for web use. Go to fonts.google.com and then select Thai from the language menu to see what's available.